# Unregister app registered with LSRegisterURL

Tags: macos

Is there any way to remove a record from Launch Services database which was added using LSRegisterURL?

I have several apps that can open the same URL and I want to manage which one of them should open it. Unfortunately now I face a problem that at some point LSRegisterURL stop working. E.g. it works until some point, then, I guess, Launch Services database (or cache) gets overflown and subsequent calls to LSRegisterURL don't have any effect.

So my idea is to clean up Launch Services database by removing old records, but I can't find any related function.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a private API in LaunchServices today that appears to do the trick. It seems to work on Mac OS X 10.7 thru 10.11. I've barely tested it yet, so YMMV:

```
extern void _LSUnregisterURL(CFURLRef url) __attribute__((weak_import));

- (void) unregisterAppAtURL:(NSURL *)appURL
{
    if( _LSUnregisterURL != NULL )
    {
        CFURLRef urlRef = (__bridge CFURLRef)appURL;
        if( urlRef )
        {
            _LSUnregisterURL( urlRef );
        }
    }
}
```

There are several other private API's similar to this (which you can find by using nm). Keep in mind that if you go private, you can't submit to the App Store. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

As it comes from the further tests OS X frees the Launch Services database itself. The exact algorithm is not clear, but rebooting Mac in most cases helps to remove the records to the missed applications and/or make the app specified by the most recent call to LSRegisterURL to become the default one.